# Mock an external service instantiated in python constructor

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-unittest, pytest-mock, confluent-kafka-python

I'm working on unit tests for a service I made that uses [confluent-kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python). The goal is to test successful function calls, exception errors, etc. The problem I'm running into is since I'm instantiating the client in the constructor of my service the tests are failing since I'm unsure how to patch a constructor. My question is how do I mock my service in order to properly test its functionality.

**Example_Service.py:**

```
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient

class ExampleService:
  def __init__(self, config):
    self.service = SchemaRegistryClient(config)

  def get_schema(self):
    return self.service.get_schema()
```

**Example_Service_tests.py**

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch.object(SchemaRegistryClient, "get_schema")
def test_get_schema_success(mock_client):
    schema_Id = ExampleService.get_schema()
    mock_service.assert_called()
```

Comment: please use the correct package name in your example code. "confluent-kafka" would error out as it is not a valid Python identifier.

Comment: Do the tests builtin to that library not do something similar to what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't creating an instance of `ExampleService`; `__init__` never gets called.

You can avoid patching anything by allowing your class to accept a client maker as an argument (which can default to `SchemaRegistryClient`:

```
class ExampleService:
    def __init__(self, config, *, client_factory=SchemaRegistryClient):
        self.service = client_factory(config)

    ...
```

Then in your test, you can simply pass an appropriate stub as an argument:

```
def test_get_schema_success():
    mock_client = Mock()
    schema_Id = ExampleService(some_config, client_factory=mock_client)
    mock_client.assert_called()
```

Comment: Your solution seems to have helped but how could I write a test if I didn't want to avoid patching?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways

mock entire class using `@mock.patch(SchemaRegistryClient)` OR
replace `@mock.patch.object(SchemaRegistryClient, "get_schema")` with

```
@mock.patch.object(SchemaRegistryClient, "__init__")
@mock.patch.object(SchemaRegistryClient, "get_schema")
```